# Getting angle between two paths of co-ordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geometry

I've been stuck with this problem for quite a while now.

I'm building a custom navigation application in iOS, I have an array of CLLocations so in array 0 I get the last two co-ordinates, get the bearing of those, then in array 1 I get the bearing of the first two co-ordinates.

I then want to calculate the angle of the turn relative to the path(Path 0 in this case) they're currently on, so I can figure out which way the user is turning.

I've tried quite a few methods found on here with no success. Has anyone any tips or recommendations

[image: Diagram of what I'm trying to do.]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update:** After reading the comments I went back and looked again as I was sure I had it right, turns out my points were stored wrong and the method I was using was right!

What worked best for me was getting the bearing of both paths, Taking the current path bearing from the previous path, and following this guideline.

```
if(self.turnAngle <= 165){
    self.turnString = LEFT;
}else if( self.turnAngle >= 165 && self.turnAngle <= 205 ){
    self.turnString = STRAIGHT;
}else if( self.turnAngle >= 205 ){
    self.turnString = RIGHT;
}
```

Comment: So you want angle between green and blue one??

Comment: `I've tried quite a few methods` - Show us the methods and then explain what didn't work about those methods

Comment: why don't you start e.g. **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)**? it seems your problem is the lack of knowledge of elementary maths.

Comment: Since you came up with your own answer, add it as an answer here and accept it so that people will see that this has a "correct" answer in the future.

Comment: Thanks Inafziger, added my answer but can't accept it for two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After reading the comments I went back and looked again as I was sure I had it right, turns out my points were stored wrong and the method I was using was right!

What worked best for me was getting the bearing of both paths, Taking the current path bearing from the previous path, and following this guideline.

```
 float previousPathBearing = //get bearing
 float currentPathBearing = //get bearing
 float angle = previousPathBearing - currentPathBearing;
 angle = angle<0?-angle:angle;


if(angle<= 165){
    //LEFT;
}else if( angle>= 165 && angle <= 205 ){
    //STRAIGHT;
}else if( angle >= 205 ){
    //RIGHT;
}
```

You'll have to excuse typos/silly mistakes as I'm quite tired, but this worked fine for me!

Comment: angle = angle<0?-angle:angle;  looks odd to me. Shouldn't it be angle = angle < 0? angle + 360 : angle;

Comment: In other words, negating a negative angle doesn't normalise it -- it reflects it in a mirror.

Comment: Hmm I tried that first but ran into issues with the results I was getting. I'll be taking another look at it tomorrow so will try this again and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 2 points on path 1 (call them p1_x1, p1_y1, and p1_x2, p1_y2), and 2 points on path 2 (call them p2_x1, p2_y1 and p2_x2, p2_y2), and you want to find the angle between the paths?

This is not hard to do. Use the `atan2` function to find the absolute angle of path 1 and path 2, and then subtract one angle from the other.

In other words, your code will work out something like this:

```
float anglePath1Radians = atan2(p1_y2 - p1_y1 / p1_x2 - p1_x1);
float anglePath2Radians = atan2(p2_y2 - p2_y1 / p2_x2 - p2_x1);

float angleDifferenceRadians = anglePath1Radians - anglePath2Radians;
```

Remember that this result will probably be in radians, so you'll need to convert to degrees.

**Alternative method**

You can use the **dot (AKA scalar) product** to find the angle by taking an inverse cosine:

```
float path1Dx = p1_x2 - p1_x1;
float path1Dy = p1_y2 - p1_y1;

float path2Dx = p2_x2 - p2_x1;
float path2Dy = p2_y2 - p2_y1;

float path1Magnitude = sqrt(path1Dx * path1Dx + path1Dy * path1Dy);
float path2Magnitude = sqrt(path2Dx * path2Dx + path2Dy * path2Dy);

float dotProduct = path1Dx * path2Dx + path1Dy * path2Dy;

float angleDifferenceRadians = acos(dotProduct / (path1Magnitude * path2Magnitude));
```